# Sups in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, footnotes, context, superscripts

In LuaLaTeX I can use the realscripts package to use superior figures as footnote marks. How can I use superior figures as footnote marks in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a font which supports the `sups` feature can enable it for the footnote number. It is also necessary to disable the default value for the `textcommand` and `numbercommand` keys which are used to create a raised number for fonts without this feature.

```
\setupbodyfont [antykwa-poltawskiego]

\setupnote
  [footnote]
  [textstyle={\feature[+][f:superiors]},
   textcommand=]

\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [headstyle={\feature[+][f:superiors]},
   numbercommand=]

\setuppapersize [A6]

\starttext
\dorecurse{10}{\convertnumber{word}{\recurselevel}\expanded{\footnote{Footnote \recurselevel}} }
\stoptext
```

[image]

When you need a solution which works for fonts with and without the `sups` feature you can create your own command for the placement of the footnote number and use the `\doifelsecurrentfonthasfeature` command to check if the current font supports the feature.

```
\define[1]\FootnoteNumber
  {\doifelsecurrentfonthasfeature{sups}
     {{\feature[+][f:superiors]#1}}
     {\high{#1}}}

\setupnote
  [footnote]
  [textcommand=\FootnoteNumber]

\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [numbercommand=\FootnoteNumber]

\setuppapersize [A6]

\starttext

\dorecurse{5}{\convertnumber{word}{\recurselevel}\expanded{\footnote{Footnote \recurselevel}} }

\switchtobodyfont [antykwa-poltawskiego]

\dorecurse{5}{\convertnumber{word}{\recurselevel}\expanded{\footnote{Footnote \recurselevel}} }

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Does your second approach entail any (serious) disadvantages? What speaks against using the more flexible, font independent solution? I am going to use this in a pandoc template, and I prefer not having to change the template when I select a different font.

Comment: Just because a font supports superscripts doesn’t mean it provides also alternatives for all numbers or letters.

Comment: @Denis In some fonts superiors are there but all messed up, e.g. in Crimson ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeF1n.png)), so you might not always want to use them even if they're available.